# How to generate start time and end time based on interval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below code.

```
$scope.Teeslots = function () {
            debugger;
            $scope.TimeValues = [];
            $scope.StartTime = $scope.TeeSheetModel.StartTime;//1
            $scope.EndTime = $scope.TeeSheetModel.EndTime; //5
            $scope.Interval = $scope.TeeSheetModel.Interval;//15
            var count = 0;

            for (var i = $scope.StartTime; i < $scope.EndTime; i++) {

                var OFFSlotStartTime = i;
                var OFFSlotEndTime = i + ':' + $scope.Interval
                var OFFSlotTime = OFFSlotStartTime + '-' + OFFSlotEndTime;

                var j = OFFSlotTime.substring(2, OFFSlotTime.length);

                $scope.TimeValues.push(OFFSlotTime);
            }


        }
```

Expected output:-

```
0-0:15
0:15-0:30
0:30-0:45
0:45:1
1:15-1:30
---
4:45-5
```

Please help me how to do?

Comment: Have you tried momentJS http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: i have seen but my requirement is not fullfilled ?

Comment: It's better to use a time library (momentjs or date in javascript) to do time manipulation to save you a lot of the basic time logics (increment hour every 60 minutes, etc)

Comment: i got the solution now it's working fine